# visual studio 2012 upgrade to .net framework 4.5.2

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am currently using Visual Studio 2012. If I want my app' target framework to be .net framework 4.5.2 do I simply install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack or do I have to use Visual Studio 2013?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637

> The .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack installs the multi-targeting
>   pack for .NET Framework 4.5.2. Developers can build applications
>   targeting the .NET Framework 4.5.2 using either Visual Studio 2013,
>   **Visual Studio 2012** or third party IDEs. You need to download the web installer instead of this package if you intend to redistribute
>   .NET Framework 4.5.2.

Comment: Thank you MrDywar. This helps a lot!